# Latest Google chrome version is acting weird

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet, desktop-computer

I'm using google chrome version: 53.0.2785.101

So i had just intalled the latest version of google chrome right off the site and it was **NOTHING** like the google chrome i've known. For one when I go up to the search bar at the top and start typing the font is **BLUE**. And another thing i've notice is right next to the site address there's this little "i" encapsulated in a circle. Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/718OW.jpg

I have never seen that before in all the years i've been using chrome. And when I click on it it says "Your connection is not private"?

Another thing i noticed is to the far right hand corner where you would click to change your setting, view history and such instead of the **usual three horizontal lines** I get **three dots stacked vertically**

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CDzv.jpg

Is anyone else getting this? Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Blue text = search related query, the "i" = information about SSL. Tbh these are just updates applied by Google, nothing abnormal and you should fully expect changes with all software you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While being suspicious of anything unexpected is good, in this case the changes you've described are perfectly normal and I'm sure have been in chrome for awhile.

As one of the commenters has pointed out the 'i' is informing you about the ssl, or lack of protection on that page;

The 3 dots menu is a carry over from android which they've continued to use as part of the overall UI.

Comment: okay. i'm going to see if i can go back to an earlier version of chrome